# Is there any software for running Direct connect hub on LAN?

Tags: file-sharing, lan

Is there any software for running Direct connect hub on LAN? Opendchub was available for 11.10 but it's development was halted long ago and there seems to be none on 12.04 repos. I need it to run on my hostel LAN. Any help for compiling the Opendchub source for 12.04 is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linuxdcpp`.

> Direct connect is a peer-to-peer (P2P) file-sharing protocol. Clients
>   connect to a central hub where they can view a list of clients or
>   users connected to them. Users can search for files and download them
>   from other clients, as well as chat with other users.
>
> The most popular Windows client implementing this protocol currently
>   is DC++. LinuxDC++ is a Linux port of DC++. Though it is primarily
>   aimed at Linux, it has been shown to work on other Unix-based
>   operating systems as well.<sup>1</sup>

To  install `linuxdcpp` get it from the Ubuntu Software Center, or by clicking below.

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linuxdcpp/)</sup>

---

**Update**: To make a new DC Hub, you can use [Open DC Hub](http://opendchub.sourceforge.net/). The page has all the necessary information, and should probably do fine.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough or I missed something on Linux DC++ but isn't it for connecting to a diect connect hub which is already made. What I need is to host the DC hub. Is there any method of making a hub on linuxdcpp?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! I have compiled opendchub from the source. However, it's production is halted and there are very few options in it. I am still in need of a nice DC hub creator.

Answer (score 0):

PtokaX can also be compiled on Linux from source. This looks like a better option than opendhub. The included readme file has detailed instruction on installing Ptokax.

http://www.ptokax.org/downloads.html